# Do locks block the access to an entire array/list/dict in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I have 4 threads which call a common function with different arguments each.
But all 4 of these threads make changes to the same list.
They may or may not be accessing the same index/key in the list.
Do I need to implements lock? and how do I proceed?

Here is my code:

```
import itertools
from threading import Thread
winr = {}
two = {}
winr=[{},{},{},{},{}]
def openfile():
    for i in range(0,5):
        filename='C:\Users\Rishabh\Desktop\\'+str(i+1)+'.txt'
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        for x in lines:
            xt=x.split(" ")
            winr[i][str(xt[0])]=[str(xt[1]),str(xt[2])]

def getmatch(start,thread_id,last_match):
    match_id=start*4+thread_id
    while match_id<last_match:
        while True:
            try:
                import urllib2,json
                response = urllib2.urlopen('https://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchDetails/V001/?match_id='+str(match_id)+'&key=C4B5D001E352AB612DCECABBFAB949B1')
            except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
                continue
            break
        r=[]
        d=[]
        team={}
        html = response.read()
        dic = json.loads(html)
        if 'result' in dic and 'radiant_win' in dic['result'] and dic['result']['human_players']==10:
            print match_id
            for a in dic['result']['players']:
                if a['player_slot']>127:
                    d.append(str(a['hero_id']))
                else:
                    r.append(str(a['hero_id']))
            if dic['result']['radiant_win']=='true':
                team[0]=r
                team[1]=d
            else:
                team[0]=d
                team[1]=r
            updatearrays(team)
        else:
            print "error",match_id
        match_id=match_id+4
                # do stuff

def updatearrays(team):
    team[0].sort()
    team[1].sort()
    winner=[]
    loser=[]
    for i in range(1,6):
        w=[]
        r=[]
        winner=list(itertools.combinations(team[0],i))
        loser=list(itertools.combinations(team[1],i))
        for d in winner:
            w.append('.'.join(str(a) for a in d))
        for d in loser:
            r.append('.'.join(str(a) for a in d))
        for k in w:
            if k in winr[i-1]:
                winr[i-1][k][0]=int(winr[i-1][k][0])+1
                winr[i-1][k][1]=int(winr[i-1][k][1])+1
            else:
                winr[i-1][k]=[1,1]
        for k in r:
            if k in winr[i-1]:
                winr[i-1][k][0]=int(winr[i-1][k][0])+1
            else:
                winr[i-1][k]=[1,0]
        winner=[]
        loser=[]

def updatefile():
   # print winr
    for i in range(0,5):
        filename='C:\Users\Rishabh\Desktop\\'+str(i+1)+'.txt'
        with open(filename,"w") as f:
            for j in winr[i]:
                tstring = str(j)+" "+str(winr[i][j][0])+" "+str(winr[i][j][1])+" \n"
                f.write(tstring)

openfile()
t1 = Thread(target=getmatch, args=(0,1,1000))
t2 = Thread(target=getmatch, args=(0,2,1000))
t3 = Thread(target=getmatch, args=(0,3,1000))
t4 = Thread(target=getmatch, args=(0,4,1000))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
updatefile()
```

The common function I was referring to is updatearray()

Comment: Try to show us the code of what you mean (read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it's unclear how the four threads access the same list.

Comment: @boardrider I just added the code, can you take a look?

Comment: Any reason why `winr` is defined twice?

Comment: @boardrider No! That's a mistake of mine. I forgot to delete the initial definition.

Comment: Please create and show a minimal file instead of the 'C:\\Users\\Rishabh\\Desktop\\1.txt' you reference. See [mcve].